# Case of Table names generated by Prisma ORM

Tags: prisma

I am using prisma ^4.12.0 in my application and use this command

> pnpm prisma migrate dev

to generate tables in my empty dev database.

This works fine, but it has different behaviour on Windows and Linux:

On Windows this command creates a table with name

> mysupercooltable

On Linux this command creates a table with name

> MySuperCoolTable

Is there a setting to enforce the same behaviour on both systems?